# My font awesome icon is stuck at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to position vertically my font awesome icon, but I can not. It should look like a circle which it does, but the icon is on the bottom of it and it should be in the middle. How do I do this? I searched for a solution, but none worked for me. :(

```css
    .container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
  
.flexing {
  display: flex;
}

.aboutus i {
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25%;
    font-size: 60px;
  color: grey;
  
}

.aboutus i:hover {
  background: lightgreen;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container">
        <h2>About us</h2>
        <hr>
        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h5>
        <section class="item flexing">
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-google-wallet" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
            
        </section>
        <div class="item">
            <div>
                <a href="#" >Learn more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use flex features like this, Check your edited class below:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
  
.flexing {
  display: flex;
}

.flexing i {
    display: flex;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: whitesmoke;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: grey;
}

.flexing i:hover {
  background: lightgreen;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<div class="container">
        <h2>About us</h2>
        <hr>
        <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h5>
        <section class="item flexing">
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-google-wallet" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                <p>Nam varius accumsan elementum. Aliquam fermentum eros in suscipit scelerisque.</p>
            </div>
            
        </section>
        <div class="item">
            <div>
                <a href="#" >Learn more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, my friend. If my answer is correct, please mark it as an answer.